# what the behind principal when picking object in the screen?

Tags: graphics, 3d

For a general 3D graphics application, we see from clicking at the windows, we can select an object in the scene graph, I am wondering what's the behind principal of this screen picking in 3D graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you will want to implement mouse picking (ray picking) like this:

- take mesh(es) and its bounding volume(s)
- transform mesh(es) and its bounding volume(s) to world space as usual (using its world matrix)
- take mouse cursor coordinates (x, y)
- unproject ("undo projection") 2D screen space mouse coordinates to 3D ray in world space using inverse view and inverse projection matrices
- check for collision between ray and mesh bounding volume (coarse, fast) and/or mesh triangles (precise, slow)
- if intersected, mark object as picked
- repeat for all objects
- if multiple objects get picked, choose nearest to camera

BTW, quick [googling](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=3d+mouse+picking) returns plenty of theoretic info on that topic with practical implementations using different programming languages.